# tomcat on aws shuts down automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat7

We've installed Tomcat 7.0.64 on an ec2 without using the tomcat ami ie do it yourself.

It runs fine however for no apparent reason, tomcat occasionally gracefully shuts down for no apparent reason. The instance continues running, just tomcat stops and the last few lines in the logs suggest it has been commanded to do so.

```
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 30, 2016 9:36:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

We start/stop using `service tomcat start` `service tomcat stop` ie via the init script, which for example runs `/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

Any ideas why this might happen in AWS?

Comment: Have you checked back further in the log for the condition or exception causing the shutdown?

Comment: yes, there is nothing

Comment: it is not being stopped via the shutdown port, we suspect it could be log rolling or operating system process doing the equivalent of a `kill <pid>`

Comment: Any findings on the above issue? because I am facing the same problem on AWS server.