# tomcat-7.0.23 shuts down automatically on aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7, tomcat8

Have installed tomcat tomcat-7.0.23  on AWS server, but the last tomcat server which I started gets down automatically.
Have gone through similar question "[tomcat on aws shuts down automatically](https://serverfault.com/q/787275/220788)", but didn't solve `my problem.
Below are the lines from catalina.out file when it shuts down.

```
05-Jul-2017 18:13:30.823 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9580"]
05-Jul-2017 18:13:30.874 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9509"]
05-Jul-2017 18:13:30.924 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
05-Jul-2017 18:13:30.930 SEVERE [pool-2-thread-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesThreads The web application [/webcommon] appears to have started a thread named [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-2)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
05-Jul-2017 18:13:31.999 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9580"]
05-Jul-2017 18:13:32.000 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9509"]
05-Jul-2017 18:13:32.001 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9580"]
05-Jul-2017 18:13:32.002 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9509"]
```

Any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had you checked system logs to see if there any clue of it root cause?
Which server is it - Linux or Windows?
If it Linux, that could be done by OOM (OutOfMemory) killer - special system process designed to kill most memory consuming process in event of free memory shortage.

Comment: Its Linux server. The same setup working perfectly fine on my local machine. but giving problem on AWS ec2 server. There is no logs printed in my system log file.

Comment: @PVR "There is no logs printed in my system log file." Do you mean there is nothing in /var/log/messages? Or you use syslog? Which Linux is it?

Comment: Yup there is nothing in my root.log file of tomcat application setup. Have RHEL 6.8 linux server.

Comment: There is no such thing as root.log. You need to check this log file: /var/log/messages